# How to STOP nfs from trying (and retrying) to mount an offline server

Tags: nfs, fstab

I have a home server running ubuntu which exports a nfs volume which I'm mounting on my laptop like this

```
-> % cat /etc/fstab
...
media:/mnt/data /home/alf/media   nfs   _netdev     0 0
```

All is good.

..until I boot up my laptop at work (or any place except my house). Then booting hangs for a couple of minuttes trying to mount this volume which obviously isn't available. Very annoying.

I've (quick) read pretty much the whole nfs man page and searched high and low for a way to say to nfs: *"look man, if you cannot reach my server, just skip it and move on, ok?"*, but I just can't find a way to do this.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the `retry` parameter to `0`:

`media:/mnt/data /home/alf/media   nfs   _netdev,retry=0     0 0`

From [nfs man page:](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs)

> **retry=n** The number of minutes that the mount(8) command retries an NFS
>   mount operation in the foreground or background before giving up. If
>   this option is not specified, the default value for foreground mounts
>   is 2 minutes, and the default value for background mounts is 10000
>   minutes (80 minutes shy of one week). If a value of zero is specified,
>   the mount(8) command exits immediately after the first failure.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried this option, but I thought n was in seconds and didn't try 0. Seems a lot of options work with very different time units.